# How to run Outlook GUI app via a Docker container

Tags: windows, docker, outlook, dockerfile

I have been googling and learning Docker, how to create a Dockerfile, then build it into an image and finally run it. The vast majority of docker containers I see run non-GUI applications.

Now I am on the need of installing Office suite into a Docker container and then run Outlook application GUI from there just as you would do from your physical or virtual machine, configure your email account and read your emails from there.

I am programming an VSTO Outlook Add-in and I would like to create a "kind" of environment for testing it where I can install my Add-in into Outlook and test it whenever I want from a fresh image. So I thought to use Docker, create an image with Office 365 installed, and every time I want to test my VSTO Outlook Add-in to create a new and fresh container from that image, install the Add-in there and test it.

I don't know if that's possible using Docker. Could you please guide me in the right direction and tell me how can achieve it?

I have found some articles as below but it looks like they do not open Outlook GUI application for sending/reading emails with your account configured just as you would do when installing it in a physical/virtual machine.

- [Office 365 installation inside docker container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/387514/office-365-installation-inside-docker-container)
- [Install microsoft office in windows container](https://blog.devgenius.io/install-microsoft-office-in-windows-container-ce05877138fd)

**Note**: I am using Windows 11 Pro and I have installed successfully [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/).

Comment: It is difficult and non-portable to run Linux GUI applications on Docker; I am not aware of a recipe to run a Windows GUI application in a container.  The setup you're describing with a full Outlook and Office installation sounds much more suited to a virtual machine than a Docker container.